# Multiple select in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, html

I have a multiple select with the first option as "All" and other options. What I'm trying to do is when "All" is selected, A, B, C, D will deselect but A, B, C, D is selected, "All" is unselected.

HTML:

```html
<select name="filter" id="filter-select" multiple="multiple">
    <option id="All" value="All">All</option>
    <option id="A" value="A">A</option>
    <option id="B" value="B">B</option>
    <option id="C" value="C">C</option>
    <option id="D" value="D">D</option>
    <option id="E" value="E">E</option>
    <option id="F" value="F">F</option>
    <option id="G" value="G">G</option>
    <option id="H" value="H">H</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function UnselectAll() {
    var select = document.getElementById('filter-select');

    if(select.options[select.selectedIndex].id != 'All' ) {
        select[0].selected = false;
    } else {
        for(var x = 0; x < select.length; x++) {
            select[x].selected = false;
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById('filter-select').addEventListener('change', UnselectAll, false);
```

My problem is that as you select the options, they will not display the unselection till you scroll out of view within the select box.

Please assist.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Small typo - You are clearing 0 together with other options, so one little change will help :

`for(var x = 1; x < select.length; x++) {`